# for-select reaches 100% CPU usage due to empty default definition

Tags: go, select, cpu

When I run the following code, something is going wrong.

```
var ch chan int
        for {
            select {
            case <-ch:
                return
            default:
            }
        }
```

What can I do to prevent 100% CPU usage?

Comment: why do you have an empty `default` block in the first place?

Comment: in general, if you just wait on a channel before returning from a function, you can just put the `<-ch` at the end of the function, before the return. for/select is only useful if your function has to handle multiple cases repeatedly.

Comment: "What can I do to prevent 100% CPU usage?" That depends. What are you trying to do? It's not possible to tell your goal from reading the broken code.

Comment: Essentially you're running a tight infinite loop until the channel is signaled. You're *explicitly asking* for 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

> What can I do to prevent 100% CPU usage?

What is your goal? What is the code *supposed* to do?

This would at least be an improvement:

```golang
    <-ch
    return
```

This will just wait until something is received on the channel, then return, without busy waiting that eats CPU cycles.